# How to lessen pain in ear when flying?

Tags: travel

This question is for all, from kids to adult, but especially kids and they feel pain when plane is going up and down due to pressure.

What are ways to keep the pain in ear minimum and help them with pain?

I think the eustacion tube is blocked for me hence doctor recommendation not to fly.

Comment: Now that you reveal a medical condition under my answer, I have removed it. And no, wearing headphones will be no use at all.

Comment: Check out https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/22455/46 and related questions there. There are devices you can put in your ear that are said to help. However if you doctor recommends not flying, at a bare minimum ask if flying with such a device would be ok.